# bash export hangs indefinitely?

Tags: software-installation, firefox

I am attempting to run a command that someone in IRC gave me to install firefox, but it hangs indefinitely.

```
echo "install firefox" && export PS1=
```

Does anyone know how to make this command finish faster?

Comment: What? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: It's a pretty useless command, but are you sure it really hangs? You should be able to continue using your shell after you've run it even though you have no prompt anymore.

Comment: @HalosGhost I'm trying to install Firefox

Comment: What distro are you on? Because no matter what distro you are on, that command won't install Firefox.

Comment: @Celada it just hangs forever

Comment: @HalosGhost I'm on Linux

Comment: There's no way this is reproducible.  It did not hang.  All `echo` does is print to the screen; as HalosGhost and Celada point out, **there is no way this installs anything** and the reason you *think* the terminal is hung is because you redefined `PS1` (the prompt) as an empty string (try typing).  You got joked on IRC.  Be careful with that; this is harmless but it could have been meaner.

Answer (score 1):

> echo "install firefox"

Will echo, i.e., print to the same console, `install firefox`.  You could put anything there, e.g., `echo "fire missiles"` will print `fire missiles`.  But even if you have some, they still won't be fired ;)

> && export PS1=

The `&&` waits for the previous command to succeed, which it will. `export` means to set a shell variable for use by this process and any subprocess.  `PS1` is a string used for the prompt.  You can see what it is normally (from a terminal where you haven't reset it) with `echo $PS1` (note the `$`).  It will probably have a lot of strange sequences in it, such as `\u` (expands to your user name) and `\w` (expands to your current working directory).

`PS1=` with nothing after it will leave the variable empty, but not hang your terminal:

```
normalprompt> export PS1=
hey, no more prompt!
bash: hey, command not found...
```

Notice I could type ("hey, no...") without a defined prompt.  The last line is the shell replying it doesn't understand the last command.

Comment: but I typed `echo $PS1` and it just jumped down a line

Comment: Yes, because it's been set to nothing.  Try it in another terminal where you have a normal prompt.  You might as well close the original one.

Comment: ...note that `export`ing an environment variable (such as `PS1`) doesn't mean it is then applied to everything currently running.  It applies only to the current process and any process it starts subsequently.